# How to use the same subdomain as a custom domain for 2 API Gateways on 2 different AWS accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, microservices, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

We are shifting towards server-less microservices architecture by having each service on a separate AWS account. We are facing a problem concerning how we should map our API Gateways to a single subdomain (api.example.com) instead of having for example (service1.api.example.com, service2.apiexample.com...) so that we have a single base URL for all of our APIs.

Currently, I found a solution that includes building an API account that acts as a mapping of all the APIs of the other accounts. However, this creates a lot of headache since we need to track which service API has been added to the accounts and which has not. It also creates an overhead since we rely on CDK for our infrastructure.

Comment: Why separate AWS accounts instead  of separate IAM users in one shared AWS account?  I have no answer to the question, it just seems like you're making this harder than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a CloudFront distribution with domain `api.example.com` and configure origin for each API Gateway.

So requests to `api.example.com/products`, for example, will hit CloudFront and map to origin `products.api.example.com`, requests to `api.example.com/orders` will map to origin `orders.api.example.com`, etc.